# Additional update of all components when redux store updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm building a Task Manager that uses Redux.

This app is required to run a timer for tasks that are moved to the "in progress" list. I did this feature with redux-sagas.

But unfortunately every second the timer value in the store is updated, my entire to-do list or specifically the component that received all the tasks as props is updated with all its children.

I do not want this because other tasks for which the timer has not been activated should not be updated. What should I do to do this?

***saga.js***

```js
import {
  takeLatest,
  call,
  put,
  delay,
  take,
} from "@redux-saga/core/effects";
import { channel } from "redux-saga";
import * as api from "./api";
function* rootSagas() {
  yield takeLatest("FETCH_TASKS_STARTED", fetchTasks);
  yield takeLatesById(["TIMER_STARTED", "TIMER_STOPPED"], handleProgressTimer);
}

function* fetchTasks() {
  try {
    yield put({
      type: "REQUEST_STARTED",
    });
    yield delay(2000);
    const { data } = yield call(api.fetchTasks);
    yield put({
      type: "FETCH_TASKS_SUCCEED",
      payLoad: { tasks: data },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({
      type: "REQUEST_FAILED",
      payLoad: { error },
    });
  }
}

//handleProgressTimer
function* handleProgressTimer({ type, payLoad }) {
  if (type === "TIMER_STARTED") {
    while (true) {
      yield delay(1000);
      yield put({
        type: "TIMER_INCREAMENT",
        payLoad: { taskId: payLoad.taskId },
      });
    }
  }
}

function* takeLatesById(actionType, saga) {
  let channelsMap = {};
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(actionType);
    const { taskId } = action.payLoad;
    if (!channelsMap[taskId]) {
      channelsMap[taskId] = channel();
      yield takeLatest(channelsMap[taskId], saga);
    }
    yield put(channelsMap[taskId], action);
  }
}

export default rootSagas;
```

***action.js***

```js
function progressTimerStart(taskId) {
  return {
    type: "TIMER_STARTED",
    payLoad: { taskId },
  };
}
function progressTimerStop(taskId) {
  return {
    type: "TIMER_STOPPED",
    payLoad: { taskId },
  };
```

***reducer.js***

```js
const initialState = {
  tasks: [],
  isLoading: false,
  error: "",
};

export default function tasks(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "TIMER_INCREAMENT":
      const tasks = state.tasks.map((t) => {
        if (t.id === action.payLoad.taskId) {
          return { ...t, timer: ++t.timer };
        }
        return t;
      });
      return { ...state, tasks: tasks };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

```js
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.props.error && <FlashMessage message={this.props.error} />}
        <TaskPage
          className="p-4"
          tasks={this.props.tasks}
          isLoading={this.props.isLoading}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you just need to adjust what data is stored where. It would make sense to store the more general information about specific tasks in a global store. But the current timer data should live in the local state within that component.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use selectors in Redux to separate the tasks